# Query output with indentation

Tags: postgresql

I have table System

```
component | subcomponent  (foreign key with subsystem table)
----------+-------------
cpu       |  1
monitor   |
lcd       |
keybord   |
mouse     |
```

subcomponent table

```
id  | name
----+-------------
1   | motherboard
1   | harddisk
1   | cdrom
```

Now  I want print with indentation

Desired output

```
cpu
   --motherboar
   --harddisk
   --cdrom
keyboard
mouse
lcd
```

How it possible?

Comment: You should leave data visualisation to the view. In other words, you should not have the query solve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using e.g. a left join and some of the string formatting functions:

```
select ... as parent, '  -- ' || coalesce(..., '') as child
from ... left join ... on ...
```

You could also union things instead, etc. to get exactly what you requested.

**BUT** you really ought to leave that up to the view, as already suggested.